# As a selection the option present in the drop-down menu to the value we get from the parameter we pass in the URL

Tags: javascript, html

I have a URL with a parameter, as shown below.

**http://example.html?name=Sport**

To retrieve the parameter I use the following lines of code:

```js
let url_string = window.location.href;
let url2 = new URL(url_string);
let name_url = url2.searchParams.get("name");
```

And so far there are no problems.

I want this parameter present in the url to be used as an option for the select, therefore already pre-set to the value that corresponds to the parameter we pass in the URL (in our case on Sport).

I tried to search on the internet but the examples I found are shown in jQuery but I only need it in Javascript.

Can anyone help me to do this?

Comment: I am not sure to understand what you want. Can you explain more? Or show us how to do it in jQuery?

Comment: `option.value = name_url;` where `option` is the variable that holds the option of the select that you want to preset.

Comment: Or if you mean that you want to preset the select to have that option chosen by default, use `select.value = name_url`

Comment: @barmar can you give me a more precise example in js please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assign `name_url` to the `.value` property of the select.

```js
let url_string = window.location.href;
let url2 = new URL(url_string);
let name_url = url2.searchParams.get("name");
document.getElementById("your-select").value = name_url;
```

Replace `your-select` with the ID of the `<select>` that you want to preset.